# Windows WSL (Ubuntu) hangs/freezes randomly when listening to ports

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Windows 10 with the Ubuntu WSL subsystem. I am a Javascript developer. I have used this setup for a while now and I am very happy with it. However, I needed to set up a new computer yesterday and on that machine, the bash keeps freezing after a couple of minutes of work.

The window simply hangs and I cannot interact with it anymore. If I try to close and restart the program it will hang on the empty black bash background. Only if I restart Windows, it starts normally again.

Is there any way to debug the Linux subsystem? Are there logs that might be helpful?

It keeps happening and interrupting my work. However I really do not want to change my setup because that leads to whole different kinds of issues.

Any suggestions might be helpful!

*Update4 (2019-05-21):*

The problem only occurs, when I run some kind of development server that is listening to a specific port (e.g. 7080). I have run my distro for more than a week without any issues, but as soon as I try to start a dev server (in this case with `ringojs`), wsl freezes after a while.

*Update3*:

There is nothing in the windows event log after a crash. I am not able to stop processes and services involved. I have tried restarting the LxssManager service, but it also hangs while shutting down and won't restart.
All Ubuntu distributions in the Store have this issue. I can start another distribution and work from that. However, if I had started a dev server on the hung system, I cannot use that port again, which makes it useless in most cases.

Only a restart fixes the problem.

*Update2*:

This is new: I changed to Ubuntu 18.04 distribution, which has also frozen by now. But now, when I start to restart it, i get an `Error:: 0x80070040`

*Update:*

I am running Windows 10 1893 (build 17134.707) with the generic "Ubuntu" distribution from the Windows store (i.e. NOT 16.04 LTS or one of the others)

Comment: What version of Windows? What version of Ubuntu WSL?

Comment: Windows 10 1803 and I am using the generic Ubuntu distribution from the Windows store.

I am Javascript developer and I have a fairly complex setup with multiple panes and "windows" using tmux and vim. This has never been an issue though.

Comment: @lukastillmann - There are multiple versions of the Ubuntu WSL in the Windows Store.  The purpose of asking for that versions is to properly isolate behavior that might be unique on a specific version.  You should edit your question and provide the necessary detail to answer your question instead of submitting comments.

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound. I have updated my original post.
It happened again today. Shouldn't there be logs somewhere that might help me debug the issue? Google didn't help me find anything about it, though.

Comment: You can use strace or event log to debug your issue. See [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md). Try to use latest Windows 10 version and Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: After it happened again a couple of hours ago, I switched to Ubuntu 18.04 which as of now hangs, too. Nothing in the event log which would give me pause, but I am not used to reading it, so I might miss stuff..

Comment: I have added some more details to my original post.

Comment: The WSL was originally installed with lxrun or via the MS app store?

Comment: via the app store

Comment: I have the same issue, if you find a solution please share it.

Comment: For now, I haven't. I actually have to change my coding routines for now, because none of the distributions work for me. I wonder whether it might be a software problem, where maybe a node dev server (which is usually running) keeps crashing the wsl. I might be able to do some tests, but I also have to actually work. Which, unfortunately, has some priority.

Comment: Any chance some of the files you're working on in WSL are pointing to other windows partitions or using symlinks pointing to files which are stored on cloud and pending on software such as OneDrive / Drive stream / Google drive and backup to be synchronized?

Comment: I've got the same issue too - is there a bug about this one in GitHub?